# PowerShell Logic

Tags: powershell, compare, logic, equals

Looking that the [help section about_Comparison_Operators of PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) I understand this:

```
PS C:\> $false,$false -eq $true
PS C:\>
```

Nothing from the left matches the right so nothing is returned not even a `$null`.

I don't understand this:

```
PS C:\> $true -eq $false,$false
True
PS C:\>
```

Is it because it's first doing `$true -eq $false` which returns **False**, and then taking that **False** and doing `$false -eq $false` which returns **True**?

**More Info**

The reason the below returns false is because it's comparing a string to an array, correct? A string is not equal to an array.

```
PS C:\> "abc" -eq "abc","def"
False
```

**Answer?**

More digging shows that `$true` is equal to an object.

```
PS C:\> $true -eq [array]
True
PS C:\> $true -eq [string]
True
PS C:\> $true -eq [int]
True
PS C:\> $true -eq [bool]
True
```

It's the values of those object that matter.

```
PS C:\> $true -eq [int]0
False
```

Comment: +1 Good question, but can I ask what you need it for? I'm having troubles seeing a scenario where I could use it.

Comment: To learn how PowerShell works. Also looking at the [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) not sure why `"abc" -eq "abc", "def"` doesn't work.

Comment: [You need to earn your strips](http://beefycode.com/post/PowerShell-Mini-game-Equality.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like fundamental questions about the behavior and features of the language like this... Give's me an excuse to read the PowerShell language specification.

You can download said specification: [2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706) and [3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389). See section 7.8.1 - Equality and relational operators.

For the first part of the question, something actually is returned - an empty array, which is illustrated by: `($false,$false -eq $true).psbase`

```
Length         : 0
LongLength     : 0
Rank           : 1
SyncRoot       : {}
IsReadOnly     : False
IsFixedSize    : True
IsSynchronized : False
Count          : 0
```

From the spec -

> If the value designated by the left operand is not a collection, the
>   result has type bool. Otherwise, the result is a possibly empty
>   unconstrained 1-dimensional array containing the elements of the
>   collection that test True when compared to the value designated by the
>   right operand.

For the second part, because the left operand is itself a bool, I think that it always be the result. This is only when the right operand is a collection.

Some examples:

```
$true -eq 1,2,3,4
$true -eq '','','',''
$true -eq '',1,$true,$false
$true -eq $null,$false,1,''
```

All of these return `$true`. Conversly all of these return `$false`

```
$false -eq 1,2,3,4
$false -eq '','','',''
$false -eq '',1,$true,$false
$false -eq $null,$false,1,''
$false -eq $true,$true,$true
```

The type of the left operand is very important. This wil return `$true`: `$false -eq 0` because the right operand is castable to the type of the left operand.

Comment: Andy's on the mark.  The logical expression is processed left to right, and the type of the left operand determines how the right operand is interpreted.  If you're having trouble visualizing the spec, break the logic down and examine the casts PowerShell is performing:
[bool]0; [bool]1; [bool]@(); [bool]@($false); [bool]@($false,$false); [bool]''; [bool]$null; #ad nauseum...

Comment: I'd expect these to evaluate the same, but they don't:          [bool](@(1) -eq 1)
[bool](1 -eq @(1))

Comment: First: `-eq` returns `1` from the collection, then cast to bool makes it `$true`. Second `-eq` returns boolean because the left operand is a scaler, and cast as a bool leaves it false. I'm not sure what PowerShell does to determine the boolean when the right operand is a collection. The spec doesn't say anything about it specifically, so its a fun game for us to deduce :D

Comment: If you replace the [int] 1's with [string] 1's they evaluate the same.

Comment: yea same thing applies, first returns an array with a single element "1" which is cast to bool (`[bool] "1" # $true`). The second, comparison to the collection returns `$false` again.

Comment: By "evaluate the same" I mean they both come back true.  [bool]('1' -eq @('1')) evaluates to True.  [bool](1 -eq @(1)) evaluates to False.

Comment: Where are Jeffery and Bruce when you need them? ... `('1' -eq @(1)) # $true`, `(1 -eq @(1)) # $false`, `('1' -eq @('1')) # $true`, `(1 -eq @(1)) # $false`. At least there's a pattern there :P

Comment: Told you it looked weird.  It's like single element [int] arrays don't follow same pattern as a single element array of any other type (at least any other type I've tested so far).

Comment: I think it's more to do with the type of the left operand.

Comment: @AndyArismendi,@mjolinor: To rephrase beefarino's comment, standard equality coerces the _right_ operand to the type of the _left_ operand and then compares _left_ and _right_. The only special case is when _left_ is a collection (then equality is tested on each element of _left_, and the matching elements returned). So for `'1' -eq @(1)` and `'1' -eq @('1')`, _right_ is coerced to the string `'1'` before comparison (`'1 0' -eq @('1','0')` will also return true, for the default value of `$OFS`); for `1 -eq @(1)`, _right_ cannot be coerced to an integer and comparison returns false.

Comment: Good explanation. I was thinking it could do the coercion, but sure enough `[int](@(1))` fails where as `[string](@('1'))` succeeds. Why does coercion fail though?

Answer (score 3):

Best guess:

It's evaluating as True because it's an array with more than one member.  An array does not have a ToBoolean() method.

As long as it's a scalar, or an array with only has one member Powershell can coerce that to a scalar and get to a ToBoolean() method on the member.  As soon as it goes to 2 or more, it always returns True, regardless of what the elemets are.  If there's no ToBoolean(), and it falls back to the default ToString() method, that's always going to evaluate to True.

Or maybe not.

Comment: I added a ToBoolean method returning false to an arraylist but the comparison returned false testing `$false -eq $array_list_with_to_bool`. So i'm not sure if it's because of the existance of a method named ToBoolean.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the `-eq` operator is evaluating their existence (aka not `$null`) rather than their value.

Similar to the IF statement perhaps?

```
PS> if("anyval"){$true}else{$false}
True
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785877/why-null-is-false-but-null-null-is-true) answer provided by @Joey might also prove useful.

Comment: Actually, I think the link you provide IS the answer.