# PowerShell multi-dimensional collection logic for -eq

Tags: powershell, equality, equals-operator

Thanks to [PowerShell Logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912721/powershell-logic/15913544#15913544), I'm familiar with some intricacies of how `-eq` works when the left operand is a collection - rather than a boolean, `-eq` will return an array of elements that equal the right operand. From the 3.0 spec:

> If the value designated by the left operand is not a collection, the
>   result has type bool. Otherwise, the result is a possibly empty
>   unconstrained 1-dimensional array containing the elements of the
>   collection that test True when compared to the value designated by the
>   right operand.

That said, I've found a case that doesn't quite make sense to me. If I declare an array with an element that is also an array, I can't actually get `-eq` to match that element:

```
$a = @( 1, @(2, 3) )
$a -eq 1              # results in an array with a single element, containing 1
$a -eq @( 2, 3 )      # results in an empty array
```

What's going on? It's not particularly easy to tell if this is PowerShell wrapping mixed-type array elements, wrapping two dimensional arrays, issues with value vs. reference type equality checks, or any subset of those.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651905/powershell-match-operator-returns-true-but-matches-is-null/8652089#8652089 . Does it answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it has to with that fact that array comparison in .NET only compares that the two objects refer to the same object, not that they have equivalent values. Consider:

```
# ~> @(2,3).Equals(@(2,3))
False

# ~> $arr = @(2,3)

# ~> $arr.Equals($arr)
True

# ~> $arr.Equals(@(2,3))
False

# ~> @(1, $arr) -eq $arr
2
3
```