# Where in the world is complete documentation for PowerShell scripting?

Tags: powershell

I started doing some powershell scripting today for my work and I can find this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849827.aspx

This shows all the Cmdlets that I am using in the scripts, but I cannot find the documentation on how to use the returned objects of these Cmdlets. For example, I am using the Get-ChildItem cmd to get all the files in a dir recursively. Then I am using a ForEach loop like this:

```
 $dest = "C:\Users\a-mahint\Documents\Testing\Dest"
                    $destlist = Get-ChildItem $dest -Recurse

                    foreach ($file in $destlist){
                    write-host "File: $file"
                    write-host $file
                    $result = test-path -path "C:\Users\a-mahint\Documents\Testing\Src\*" -include $file.Name
                        if (-not $result){
                          Copy-Item $file -Destination "$backup"
                        }

                    }
                    write-host "Done copying deleted files"
```

Except I have no idea what type of object a $file is...In the documentation above, it just says it outputs a System.Object, but that doesn't help at all. I want to know all the properties of this object so I can use them to debug.

Comment: Based on your code above, `$dest` is under c:\, which is a PSDrive which uses the file system provider. When you use Get-ChildItem with that type of provider, you get a sequence of `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` objects, either `DirectoryInfo` or `FileInfo` depending on whether each item is a directory or file.

Comment: $file.GetType() will reveal it is actually a FileInfo or DirectoryInfo, based on System.IO.FileSystemInfo.

Comment: @EBGreen post that as your solution. That's what I used

Comment: I would except that it doesn't answer the question that you actually asked. It answers a specific subset applying to the specific issue that you were trying to resolve. In a general sense though, Get-Help, Get-Command, and Get-Member should be your three most frequently used cmdlets while you are learning Powershell.

Answer (score 2):

From a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912721/powershell-logic) I asked one time [Andy Arismendi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251123/andy-arismendi) supplied some links for me to read.

> You can download said specification: [2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706) and [3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389).

```
$file = Get-Item C:\foo.txt
```

Remember there is a `$file | Get-Member` command you can use to view the objects methods and properties. Also since everything in PowerShell is an Object you can always do `$file.GetType()` and then [Bing that type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US" -Filter *.txt

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent reference for get-childitem.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176841.aspx

What kind of file details are you needing exactly?